# Java work with class as collection to add items

Tags: java, android

This class below is my simple code which it is deployed  `ModelMarkets` and I want to add item to this class `List` but I can't. Please help me to implement that.

**My base class:**

```
public class ModelMarkets extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String marketId;
    private String marketTitle;

    ...
}
```

And create a list from that and add an item to that class:

```
public class ModelMarketLists {
    private List<ModelMarkets> modelMarkets = new ArrayList<>();

    public ModelMarketLists(List<ModelMarkets> modelMarkets) {
        this.modelMarkets = modelMarkets;
    }

    public ModelMarketLists(JSONArray lists) {

    }

    public void add(ModelMarketLists t){
        /* modelMarkets.addAll(t); */
    }

}
```

How can I add class collection data to `modelMarkets` as `List` ?

Comment: `modelMarkets.addAll(t.modelMarkets);`? What are you actually trying to do in the last block? Add a `ModelMarkets` to a `ModelMarketLists`?

Comment: @JornVernee i'm so sorry sir, that was wrong paste code, i updated code, it seems `modelMarkets.addAll(t.modelMarkets);` was correct,please let me to test that

Answer (score 2):

The type `ModelMarketLists` has a method `public void add(ModelMarketLists t)` but you are trying to invoke `add(ModelMarkets)`, which will only work if `ModelMarkets` is a subtype of `ModelMarketLists` or if `ModelMarketLists` contains an overload like `public void add(ModelMarkets modelMarkets)`.

Also, you should follow the Java naming conventions. Local variable names should start with a lower-case letter, be spelled in camel case, be long enough to be meaningful, reflect correct natural-language spelling, and reflect the semantics of the variable in the problem domain.

Comment: ok,thanks i fixed my code, now my code is `public void add(ModelMarkets t) {    modelMarkets.addAll(t);   }`. but i can not add list to that such as : `ModelMarketLists list = new ModelMarketLists();
list.add(new ModelMarkets("1","test","test"));`